Unable to specify wwilakehouse as Destination Lakehouse in Microsoft Fabric
I am a beginner in using Micrsoft Fabric. Currently I follow the Lakehouse tutorial to create an end-to-end data pipeline.
In step 4 Ingest data after building a lakehouse, I would like to specify wwilakehouse as Lakehouse from Destination tab. However, the wwilakehouse  does not show up, even though it should have been created in step 3 Build a lakehouse.
I have cleaned up resources and started again from scratch, but still I could not specify wwilakehouse as Destination Lakehouse.
What are the underlying reasons? Could I miss some steps? Any advice is welcome.

Can you verify that the wwilakehouse has actually been created? Do you see it under the list of lakehouses if you navigate to your workspace?

are you in the same workspace?

From the workspace the wwilakehouse was actually created.
I was also in the same workspace.
After consulting MS Support, this problem rose up because the "semantic model are always in sync" - step 2 to Build a Report from 3 Build a Lakehouse was missed.
